# Collecting terms from an indexed sum

Tags: summation, algebraic-manipulation

How can I get Mathematica to collect terms from an indexed sum? My application is somewhat convoluted, but this minimum code captures the idea:

```
s[i_, n_] := 
 Sum[l[i, j]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] + Sum[m[i, j]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] + 
  Sum[l[i, j]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}] + Sum[m[i, j]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}]
```

I'm trying to use Collect to report $\sum _ {j = 1}^n e (c (j)) [l (i, j) + m (i, j)] + \sum _ {j = 1}^n e (z (j)) [l (i, j) + m (i, j)]$

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

s[i_, n_] :=
 Sum[l[i, j]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
  Sum[m[i, j]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
  Sum[l[i, j]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
  Sum[m[i, j]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}]
```

The simplified form is

```
s2[i_, n_] :=
 Evaluate@(Sum[l[i, j]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
     Sum[m[i, j]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
     Sum[l[i, j]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
     Sum[m[i, j]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}] //.
    Sum[x_*y_, {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] +
      Sum[z_*y_, {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] :>
     Sum[y*(x + z), {v, vmin, vmax}])
```

Which simplifies to a single sum.

```
s2[i, n]

(* Sum[(e[c[j]] + e[z[j]])*(l[i, j] + m[i, j]), {j, 1, n}] *)
```

Checking

```
k = 8;

And @@ Flatten[Table[s[i, n] == s2[i, n] // Simplify, {i, k}, {n, k}]]

(* True *)
```